# Equivalent of org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean for non-Boot Spring project?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, spring-bean, spring-session

I'm trying to implement external session handling in Spring, as per [this tutorial](http://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/session-handling-with-spring/).  I'm having some trouble adding the right filter though.  Spring Boot appears to have defined the proper bean/filter, but my project is not Spring Boot, so it cannot find the `FilterRegistrationBean`.  Is there some sort of equivalent to this class in non-Boot versions of Spring?  I also tried [org.springframework.web.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BOOTSTRAP-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean.html), but can't get it to import properly (it looks like this documentation refers to a SNAPSHOT version, so perhaps this package was never part of a proper release).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your container configuration, web.xml or `ServletContainerInitializer`, you can register a [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) filter and make it refer, by name, to a `Filter` bean you've declared in your `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: That makes sense, but I still need a `Filter` bean, and it seems kind of like reinventing the wheel to write my own Filter class.

Comment: @JosephBlair I don't understand. If you want your own `Filter`, you need to write you own `Filter`. However, since `Filter`s are managed by the Servlet container, you can't have it be a Spring bean. Spring's solution for this is to declare your `Filter` as a bean then register a `DelegatingFilterProxy` as a Servlet `<filter>` which then delegates to your `Filter` bean found in the root application context. The javadoc I linked to explains all this.

Comment: I understand all of that, but I don't really want "my own" `Filter`, I just want the `FilterRegistrationBean` since it has already implemented all of the logic instead of trying to replicate what it does in a custom-created `Filter` class.  However, I can't use it since my project is not Spring Boot, so I'm looking for an equivalent that I can use.

Comment: @JosephBlair `DelegatingFilterProxy` is the equivalent. Instead of being declared as a bean, it's declared as a Servlet `<filter>` in XML (web.xml) or through the `ServletContext` in a `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense now, thanks!  I apologize for the misunderstanding.  The `DelegatingFilterProxy` doesn't seem to be finding my bean though.  Could this be an issue of my bean being defined in the wrong `Context`?  I put it in the same XML config file as all of the other beans.

Comment: @JosephBlair Typically you'd have 2 context, [a root and a servlet context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610490/difference-between-root-and-web-applicationcontext-spring-mvc). The root context is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. The servlet context is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Your `Filter` bean should be declared in the root context. That's where the `DelegatingFilterProxy` will look for it.